# Display user specific info into a title tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

my question is on how to display user info thats in a list specific to that user when the person hovers over their name. I have made the list, but i want to get data from database and have it append as a tooltip or a popup of their info. I have used flask to put data info the title section of my element, but it will display one users name for all of them. Heres some code.

```
HTML:
<div id='avdiv'>
  <h1 id='myh1av'>Available</h1>
  <ol id='avlist'>
    <li id='avli'></li>
  </ol>
</div>

Flask
@app.route('/allfirefightersavailability', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def allfirefightersavailability():
info = FireFighter.query.filter_by(availability='AVAILABLE').all()
avlist = []
for i in info:
    avlist.append({'name':i.name, 'availability': i.availability, 'time': 
    i.avtimestamp})
return jsonify(avlist)

JS
setInterval(function(){
allfirefightersavailability()
}, 1000);


function allfirefightersavailability(){
$('#avlist').children().remove(),
$.getJSON('/allfirefightersavailability',
function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    $('#avlist').append("<li id='avli'>" + data[i].name + '|' + data[i].time 
    + "</li>" + '<br><br>')
    $('#avli').tooltip(data[i].name)  //<---This Keeps Giving Me A Type 
                                  //Error: $(...).tooltip() is not a 
                                                            //function 
    }
});
}

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='retrieve.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want hovering an element and showing some info, you can use `title` to do that

Simple demo like below:

```html
<ul>
  <li title="1st">A</li>
  <li title="2nd">B</li>
  <li title="3rd">C</li>
</ul>
```

In you case:

Note that id should be unique.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    $('#avlist').append("<li id='avli'"+ i +" title='"+ data[i].name +"'>" + data[i].name + '|' + data[i].time + "</li>" + '<br><br>')

}
```